# HTML File Input Filter for Multiple Extensions

Tags: html, file, input, file-extension

I am writing a web form through which users can upload files. Using the `accept` attribute of the `<input type="file">` allows me to specify single-extension files to filter but I would like to expand this to now filter multiple-extension files e.g. `.tar.gz`.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Doesn't seem to work when ``accept=".tar.gz"``. Surely this should have been contemplated in potential use... hence my question.

Comment: It seems to work with `accept=".tar.gz"` on Chrome 114 / Windows 10. On which browser and operating system have you encountered this problem?

Comment: Interesting that it should work for you on Chrome. I'm using Firefox but I've also tested on Chrome and Safari but it still doesn't work. Perhaps it's an OS issue because I'm using macOS.

Comment: When searching I've found opened issue on [chromium forum](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=521781) about this exact use case and it's marked as 'wont fix' because that's OS specific thing. Best you can do is to accept MIME type for compressed archives I guess.

Answer (score 0):

have you use ',' to distinguish between two file extensions?

```
<input type="file" accept=".tar,.gz" />
```

[sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IvnFb.png)

Comment: This will match `.tar` files AND `.gz` files. I want to match `.tar.gz` files as distinct from `.foo.gz` files. This solution doesn't solve my problem.